# Converting JTable into PDF File

Tags: java, swing, pdf

How to convert `JTable` into `.pdf` file format using [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/). I want to show the report for gym management system in Java using eclipse. I want to show logo, administrator's details and then table of report. I already visit [Example_08](http://pdfjet.com/java/by-example.html), but I am not satisfied with that answer.

Comment: How to convert JTable into pdf File format ? using PDFjet jar.

Comment: Post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for getting answer.

Comment: what problem you are facing? do you have the problem in running application using `PDFjet` or do you have problem in exporting the data in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Example03 and combine that with Example08.

Also - what is the specific problem?

did you get a (basic) PDF from that lib?
where you able to add own data to the PDF?
can you change layout?